# header location не перенаправляет

Tags: php

Подскажите, почему у меня конструкция вида:

```
header("Location: /page.html"); 
exit;
```

Не перенаправляет на нужную страницу. В консоли только пишет ответ 302 потом целевой адрес с ответом 200. Типа все гуд, но мы остаемся при этом на первой странице...
http://prntscr.com/km2psx

UPD:

Так тоже не работает:

```
header("Location: http://site.ru/page.html"); 
exit;
```

Comment: А полный адрес указывать не нужно? Официальное [описание](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).

Comment: Я так тоже пробовал. Результат тот же...

Comment: Если перенаправление не работает, то есть большая вероятность, что вы вывели что-то на экран. `header` можно менять **ДО** вывода любых данных

Comment: @ArchDemon, А вы можете посмотреть код на сайте, я дам вам доступ. А то никак не пойму как решить проблему. Видимо где-то другая функция срабатывает, которая осуществляет вывод перед header